# Как отправить методом POST данные в серверной Java?

Tags: java, http, сервер

Когда пользователь появляется на "нашем" сайте, мы получаем `HttpServletRequest` и `HttpServletResponse`. Используем данные из реквест чтобы сформировать переменные и отправить постом, затем можно использовать респонс, чтобы сделать `sendRedirect` для переправки на "чужую" страницу. Беда в том, что `sendRedirect` не поддерживает отправку методом `POST`, только `GET`'ом

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу предложить только хак. А именно вам нужна своя страница, на которую вы будете редиректить запрос, и уже на этой странице нужно выполнить POST запрос к "чужому" ресурсу с помощью JavaScript.